# React-flow how to get edges to separate before hitting target node

Tags: reactjs, react-flow

I'm using react-flow and I'd like the edges to separate before they reach the target node. So basically, the lines above "Validating Previous Actions" should end at different parts at the top instead of all combining in the middle. I haven't seen anything in the documentation about this, does anyone know how to do this?

[image]